# Finding the matrix of a projection map and finding the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of $(v_{1},v_{2})$ with $v_1 = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$ and $v_2 = (\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$. We must find the matrix $M$ of this projection $P$ (with respect to the standard basis).

Also, it is then required to show by direct calculation that $M^{2} = M$ and finally the eigenvalues of such matrix must be identified.

Could someone assist me in solving this? Thanks! Helen

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it is easy to check that $v_1$ and $v_2$ is orthogonal, and even better, orthonormal (that is $v_i^Tv_j=\delta_{ij}$). So the matrix you are searching for is just

$M=v_1v_1^T+v_2v_2^T$

Generally, given matrix $Q$ with orthonormal columns, that is, $Q^TQ=I$, the projection matrix is just

$P=QQ^T$

note that $Q$ is not necessarily square.

More generally, for a projection onto the column space of any matrix $A$ (with linear independent column vectors), the projection matrix is given by

$P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

You might want to check *singular value decomposition* (*svd*) for details

Comment: Thank you, I will try this method!